# Is generation of electric/ magnetic field due to motion of charge frame dependent?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation

Was introduced to electrostatics today. So I do not have much idea about it and neither I have a strong background in physics. Just a highschool student

Comment: Then maybe wait till the next lesson? I'm sure this will come up.
But without knowing what you already learnt it's hard to answer without spoiling... ^^
Do you know the electric field of a point charge at rest? The magnetic field of an electric current? Those two might already be used to construct an answer.

Comment: Nearly identical to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/341809/is-the-presence-of-a-magnetic-field-frame-dependent).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are yet acquainted with the magnetic field, but remember, that charge generates the electric field (the E-field), but the current (moving charge) generates the magnetic field (the B-field).

So yes, magnetic field depends on the frame of the reference. An intuitive example would be a charged rod. If it is stationary, it only generates the E-field. But if we would be in the moving frame of reference, it would be the same as if the charges inside the rod would be moving. According to the [Ampère's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law) (which describes the B-field on the closed loop) it would generate the magnetic field.